# Pagination of GridView which is inside a DataList

Tags: c#, asp.net

My requirement is to show all the countries from database, and for each countries I have to display its respective states.

So, for displaying all the countries i used DataList.
OnItemDataBound function of that `DataLIst I have binded the gridview for displaying its respective states.

Now, I want to give pagination for that inner gridview which is in the datalist.

I dont know how to handle the gridview pagination  which is inside a datalist.

I have binded grid view as ,

```
protected void dataListCountries_OnItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
{       
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        HiddenField hdn = (HiddenField)e.Item.FindControl("hdnCountryID");
        GridView grd = (GridView)e.Item.FindControl("grdDetails");

        objCountries = new Countries();
        lstCountries = objCountries.getallCountries();
        grd.DataSource = lstCountries ;
        grd.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Please any one of you provide a solution for me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can do it using the NamingContainer property

Comment: can you put your gridbinding  code in the fiddle/ here so that it will be easy to answer

Comment: @Gangadhar I have given my grid binding code. Once check it out..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your are binding the gridview with some input parameter from the datalist item, then you need to have a label to hold it in the datalist.

```
protected void gv_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            GridView gv = (sender as GridView);
            DataListItem DLItem= (DataListItem)gv.NamingContainer;
            //Label Id = (Label)DLItem.FindControl("lblId");

            gv.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;

            //Your gridbinding code
    HiddenField hdn = (HiddenField)DLItem.FindControl("hdnCountryID");
    //GridView grd = (GridView)e.Item.FindControl("grdDetails");

    objCountries = new Countries();
    lstCountries = objCountries.getallCountries();
    gv .DataSource = lstCountries ;//lstOrders;
    gv .DataBind();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

           // return;
        }

    }
```

Included grid binding code.Here i think you are not using hidden field value for binding the grid. And i think you need to bind the grid with lstCountries not lstOrders.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this 
in which gv is gridview and namingcontainer is datalist which is parent
datasettable is the data to be bind
clsCommon.GridViewPopulate for biinging grid
I hope this is helpfull
write in pageindexchanging property

```
 protected void gv_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            GridView grd= (sender as GridView);
            GridViewRow gvrow = (GridViewRow)grd.NamingContainer;

             objCountries = new Countries();
    lstCountries = objCountries.getallCountries();
    grd.DataSource = lstOrders;
    grd.DataBind();

            gv.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            return;
        }

    }
```